# How to combine two PDF content

Tags: itext

[Here are two pdf files which pagesize are A4. Their content height is half of A4 and another part is blank. Now I want to combine two A4 pdf files into one A4 pdf file with itext or itextsharp. I have tried to many times by using pdfStamper or pdfcopy class but it does not work. So I ask for some help,Please tell me some useful information about that. Thanks very much!

the source pdf files:

[image: click here to see the source pdf files]

the combined pdf:

[image: click here to see the combined pdf]

the first image is show the source two pdf files's content, the second image is show the result I want.

Comment: How did you manage to draw all those red lines with iTextSharp?

Comment: _"I have tried to many times"_ -> show us the code you tried.

Comment: This task essentially is a simplified variant of the [NUpTool](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5JS/repos/book/browse/src/part2/chapter06/NUpTool.java); in contrast to that tool you always use the original page size (you don't rotate it), you don't scale down the page contents, and you arrange top to bottom first, not left to right.

Comment: Since you're new at iText, why are you using an old version of iTextSharp? Use iText 7, and take a look at the .Net tutorial: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents Try those examples, and explain what in your code doesn't work.

Comment: I  accept Bruno Lowagie's advice and take a look at the itext 7. It seems like that itext 7 can solve my problem! I will take a try. Thanks every one here!